# Bootstrap not lining up sections for navigation hover properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I'm having an issue where when I scroll through my homepage with the anchor tag sections it does not line up properly. For instance, if I click "showcase" it will go to the section but not highlight the navigation hover like it should. However, if I scroll slightly down it will then hover.

*I read online in the past this was resolved by adding padding into the css for the section tag. I couldn't seem to get it to work.*

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**BQ:** How do I change the active section the page opens to? I tried changing the "active" tag, but it still uses the same section.

I'm using this template: http://www.blacktie.co/demo/pratt/#home

Answer (score 0):

you have two identical ID's on your page , eg #showcase. Other then that you probably need to set an offset in the jquery scrollto function.

Comment: I also noticed the two IDS on the template.. do you think it's safe to delete the one that isn't the section? Sorry to sound so amateur, but what exactly would the offset look like? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just put all your content in the <section> and then remove the internal second wrapper element. I am not sure why you have both Scrollto and localscroll plugins in your site, but I guess you can just use scrollTo only? and then activate it with an offset option which it provides: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/